# 85W MagSafe adapter has stopped working

Tags: macbook-pro, power, magsafe

Yesterday I noticed that my 85W MagSafe adapter had stopped working.

I usually leave it plugged in constantly to my MacBook Pro (but not constantly on at the switch).

The LED on the plug that connects to the MacBook Pro no longer lights up (I don't get any colour light whatsoever).

Apple are sending a replacement adapter out in the post but that will take 3 days so I was wondering if there are any secrets that could get it back working in the meantime?

So far I've tried leaving it unplugged and then using another plug as per a post I read online about some sort of 'automatic protection' but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you have a close look at the plug?  And at the place it connects to on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the pins of the MagSafe that carry the power were physically stuck, the fault isn't something you could or should fix. Hopefully Apple's diagnosis is correct and you don't need a repair of the Mac instead of a repair of the adapter.

You'll discover that in three days time unless you can test with another MagSafe adapter in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a cloth or a Q-tip and carefully clean the pins on the MagSafe cable with isopropyl (rubbing) alcohol. Wait until the pins are dry before plugging the cable into your MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on holiday.  With the nearest store stocking Apple adaptors thousands of miles away, my face turned white.

In a plain desperate attempt I touched the adaptor's end points with my tongue and felt there still was power coming out.  The problem just became worse - it was not the adpator which was faulty but the Macbook!

By accident I discovered some small iron particles attracted the magnets around the macbook side of the connector.  Used cotton buds to wipe them off and everything worked again.